# Calcular diferença entre dois horários

Tags: java

Estou com dúvida na lógica desse código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int horaInicial = sc.nextInt();
        int minutoInicial = sc.nextInt();
        int horaFinal = sc.nextInt();
        int minutoFinal = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        int instanteInicial = horaInicial * 60 + minutoInicial;
        int instanteFinal = horaFinal * 60 + minutoFinal;
        int duracao;
        if (instanteInicial < instanteFinal) {
            duracao = instanteFinal - instanteInicial;
        }
        else {
            duracao = (24 * 60 - instanteInicial) + instanteFinal;
        }
        int duracaoHoras = duracao / 60;
        int duracaoMinutos = duracao % 60;
        System.out.println("O JOGO DUROU " + duracaoHoras + " HORA(S) E " + duracaoMinutos + " MINUTO(S)");
    }
}
```

O código é equivalente ao [uri1047](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1047), estou com dificuldades em entender o código de resolução citado, exclusivamente na linha:

```
duracao = (24 * 60 - instanteInicial) + instanteFinal;
```

Não compreendo porque subtrair o `instanteInicial` de 1440 (24 * 60) e depois somar com `instanteFinal`, sei que 1440 é igual a 1 dia em minutos.

Comment: Você não entende o código que você fez?

Comment: Eu não estava a conseguir resolver esse problema, então pesquisei uma resolução no git e achei essa e gostaria de entende-la, apenas não entendi a linha: duracao = (24 * 60 - instanteInicial) + instanteFinal;

Comment: É porque - pelo que entendi - o jogo pode terminar no dia seguinte. Por exemplo, se começa às 22h e termina 3 da manhã (do dia seguinte, suponho), então ele entra no `else` e para compensar o fato da hora final ser menor (3 < 22), ele soma mais 24 horas (para "compensar", ou para "acrescentar" as horas do dia seguinte). E na verdade nem precisava desses parênteses, só estão aí pra confundir...

Comment: Dito isso, eu não gosto muito do URI online porque muitos problemas são assim: não dão todos os requisitos e vc tem que ficar adivinhando as situações que ele vai testar, como é o caso aqui. Dá até pra "adivinhar" esse critério com base nos exemplos, mas o enunciado teria que ser mais claro, na minha opinião, senão vira mais um joguinho do que aprendizado de fato (ainda mais pra um site que diz ter o objetivo de "*provide programming practice and knowledge sharing*").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linha de código em questão poderia ser mais clara se tivesse sido escrita assim:

```
duracao = (24 * 60 + instanteFinal) - instanteInicial;
```

Perceba que é totalmente equivalente ao que foi escrito acima (mudando apenas a ordem da soma e da subtração). O que essa linha faz então é o seguinte: se o instante final parece ser menor que o instante inicial, é que provavelmente pertence ao dia seguinte e não ao mesmo dia que o instante inicial. Para concretizar isso, apenas acrescente um dia ao instante final (deslocando ele assim um dia no futuro).